# get image Object by path on mobile (Ionic + Cordova + Angular )

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building a mobile app with Ionic/Cordova/Angular and I don't know how to get a image file by path (to be sent it to the server).

I'm using this example (http://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/ ) to get and save the image in app folder.

So I have an **image name** and an **image path** and I want to get somehow the image object to be able to convert it in base64 and send it to the server.

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE:**

```
    `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL($scope.user.image, onSuccess, onError); 
    function onSuccess(entry) { 
        /* Here:  entry look like this : 
            "isFile":true, "isDirectory":false, "name":"myImgName1234", "fullPath": "/myImgName1234", "filesystem":"FileSystem:files>", "nativeURL":"file:///data/data/com.example.DemoApp/files/myImgName1234"
        */          
        $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, entry.name)
        // I also tried : $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(entry.nativeURL, entry.name) or $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(entry.fullPath, entry.name)
        .then(function (success) {
            // success
            window.alert('Succes read= '+ JSON.stringify(success));                             
        }, function (error) {
            // error
            window.alert('Error read= '+ JSON.stringify(error));                
        });
    }
    function onError(error){
        window.alert('error' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }`
```

What I have also tried 
    Error code: 5    <- $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, entry.name)
    Error code: 5    <- $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(entry.nativeURL, entry.name) 
    Error code: 1000 <- $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(entry.fullPath, entry.name)
    Error code: 1    <- $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(entry.name)

Is there any way to get the image Object (binary) if you know the path with cordova ? not just the image properties object (fileEntry)

Answer (score 2):

use this plugin to get the file from the device: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/
and then do what ever you want with it.

have you used the ngCordova plugin? your code should look something like this:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaFile) {
     $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "file_name.txt")
         .then(function (success) {
             console.log(success);
         }, function (error) {
             console.log(error);
     });
});
```

Comment: I tried with file plugin but I'm doing something wrong. I updated the question with the errors I got.

Comment: sure. I'm using ngcordova, but even if I do checkFile or readAsDataURL I get Error code 5 or 1000 as I mentioned in the question. I cannot find any solution ...

Comment: is the entry.file the image object that I have to send to server ?

Comment: it looks like it can't find the service. have you included 'ngCordova' in app.js and $cordovaFile in your controller? also check you have installed the file plugin. If you have done all of that, please test and inspect your app on a real device.

Comment: I have everything installed and included and I'm testing only on a real device (Galaxy S4) I have also tried readAsBinaryString method but I get error code 1000 ...

Comment: The flow is like this: I take/choose a picture from my device and I take that picture and move it into my app folder. I know the img name and the img path and when I will send the image to the server I need  the binary image .I tried  $cordovaFile.readAsBinaryString(PATH, entry.name) and for path I have tried: cordova.file.dataDirectory, entry.fullPath, entry.nativeURL but didn't work ... I think path is not ok ...

Comment: you probebly have a syntax error. take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57hsxvCrBdE. Its allows you to use your console in your real device and it get you to your error